# How do I find out if a combination of numbers are in another combination of numbers?

Tags: python, range, combinations

Is there a way to find out if a combination of numbers (stored in a list) are in a longer combination of numbers (stored in a separate list)?

E.g.

```
mylist = [(1, 4, 7), (3, 6, 9)]

serieslist = list(itertools.combinations((range(1, 50)), 5))
>> [(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), (1, 2, 3, 4, 6), (1, 2, 3, 4, 7)...etc...]
```

In the example above, I would want to return that the combination of numbers `(1, 4, 7)` *is* in the combination of numbers `(1, 2, 3, 4, 7)`.

Specifically though, I *don't* want to split `(1, 2, 3, 4, 7)` into further combinations of three.

Ideally, I'd like to write this into a `for` statement to compare each element of `mylist` to each element of `serieslist`.

Comment: Are those combinations, or sets? If they really are sets, you could represent each "combination" as a bitset (having one bit set for each number present). Then, the test would be a subset test, which would be a matter of doing an AND of the two bitsets, such as ((sub & set) == sub).

Comment: Hi migle, they're combinations. I'm actually creating combos in mylist from a series of numbers elsewhere, but I just wanted to simplify for the purpose of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sets to see if a your tuple is part of the larger tuple:

```
if set(short_tuple).issubset(longer_tuple):
    # all elements of short_tuple are in longer_tuple
```

You want to turn `short_tuple` into a set *once*:

```
for short_tuple in mylist:
    short_tuple_set = set(short_tuple)

    for combo in itertools.combinations((range(1, 50)), 5):
        if short_tuple_set.issubset(combo):
            # matched!
```

It'd be more efficient to generate all combinations that are *guaranteed* to be matches though:

```
for short_tuple in mylist:
    short_tuple_set = set(short_tuple)

    remainder = (i for i in range(1, 50) if i not in short_tuple_set)
    for combo in itertools.combinations(remainder, 5 - len(short_tuple)):
        combo = sorted(combo + short_tuple)
```

Each `combo` is a valid combination of 5 numbers between 1 and 49 inclusive that have all 3 numbers of the `short_tuple` in them, **without** having to create all possible combinations.

If you create these as generator functions, you can verify that they produce the same output (apart from tuples versus lists; `sorted()` returns a list):

```
>>> def set_test(mylist):
...     for short_tuple in mylist:
...         short_tuple_set = set(short_tuple)
...         for combo in itertools.combinations((range(1, 50)), 5):
...             if short_tuple_set.issubset(combo):
...                 yield combo
... 
>>> def create_combos(mylist):
...     for short_tuple in mylist:
...         short_tuple_set = set(short_tuple)
...         remainder = (i for i in range(1, 50) if i not in short_tuple_set)
...         for combo in itertools.combinations(remainder, 5 - len(short_tuple)):
...             combo = sorted(combo + short_tuple)
...             yield combo
... 
>>> all(a == tuple(b) for a, b in itertools.izip_longest(set_test(mylist), create_combos(mylist)))
True
```

but the second method is *so* much faster:

```
>>> timeit('list(f(mylist))', 'from __main__ import set_test as f, mylist', number=10)
14.483195066452026
>>> timeit('list(f(mylist))', 'from __main__ import create_combos as f, mylist', number=10)
0.019912004470825195
```

Yes, that is nearly **1000 times** faster.

Comment: Hi Martijn, your efficient combination solution looks ideal for what I am trying to do. Would I be right in thinking that if a new short_tuple_set appeared in a combo which has already been created, that combo would be created again? In this case, that is exactly what I am hoping for.

Comment: Not certain what you are asking here; we generate a new sequence of combinations for each short tuple in your input list.

Comment: Not to worry Martijn, my question wasn't clear but I have answered it myself. Your answer was spot on.

Answer (score 0):

If all your sequences only contain unique numbers (no duplicates):

```
a = (1,4,7)
b = (1,2,3,4,7)
a_in_b = all(x in b for x in a)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Kirinyale. It is my anticipation that the sequences in mylist WILL contain duplicates, but that the sequences in  serieslist will not.